# sharing resource objects through state controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

What are the posible ways for sharing resource objects  through state controllers.
I am using $rootScope, state inheritance or factories (services). Is there any other ways to send resource objects to other controllers on state changes?

Comment: You can use $rootScope or services or broadcasting events. Recommended is to use services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to coordinate complex transactions on the same object (or set of objects) across multiple controllers, then services are definitely the way to go. However, the master branch of UI Router implements [typed parameters](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/1032), which allow URL parameters to be converted to complex objects and exposed on `$stateParams`.

Any controller that access to parameter values on `$stateParams` will have access to the parameter objects.

Comment: It seems that I should stay sticked on services. Thanks for the tip by the way.